# Mobx consecutive getting computed values produces different references

Tags: mobx

```
class Store {
    @computed get staticItems(): number[] {
        return [1, 2, 3]
    }
}

describe('mobx', () => {
    it('computed static items should be same', (done) => {
        let store = new Store();
        let items = store.staticItems;
        setTimeout(() => {
            expect(items).toBe(store.staticItems);
            done()
        }, 500);
    });
})
```

Testing with **jest** throws

```
Expected: [1, 2, 3]
    Received: serializes to the same string

      50 |         let items = store.staticItems;
      51 |         setTimeout(() => {
    > 52 |             expect(items).toBe(store.staticItems);
```

This tests passes with `toEqual` but fails with `toBe` which means both references points to different objects. What am I missing? Working with react this will unnecessarily change props for child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MobX computed values are automatically suspended when not used inside a reaction. From the [documentation](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html):

> This automatic suspension is very convenient. If a computed value is no longer observed, for example the UI in which it was used no longer exists, MobX can automatically garbage collect it. This differs from `autorun`'s values where you must dispose of them yourself. It sometimes confuses people new to MobX, that if you create a computed property but don't use it anywhere in a reaction, it will not cache its value and recompute more often than seems necessary. However, in real life situations this is by far the best default, and you can always forcefully keep a computed value awake if you need to, by using either `observe` or `keepAlive`.